# Найти предыдущую серию сериала, даже если она в другом сезоне

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SET @current_episode = 1;
SET @current_season = 2;
SET @current_serial = 2;

SELECT * FROM `episode` _episode 
    LEFT JOIN season _season ON _episode.season_id = _season.id
    LEFT JOIN serial _serial ON _season.serial_id  = _serial.id 
WHERE 

    (_episode.episode < @current_episode AND _season.season = @current_season)
        OR 
    (_episode.episode > @current_episode AND _season.season = (@current_season - 1))

ORDER BY _season.season DESC, _episode.episode ASC
LIMIT 0,1
```

Таблица `Episode`:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| season_id   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                              |
| poster_id   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| episode     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                              |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Таблица `Season`:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| serial_id  | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| season     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

Таблица `Serial`:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
```

Comment: А какой диалект `sql`? `ms-sql`, `my-sql`, `oracle` и т.д.?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov MySQL

Comment: А может в order by episode DESC ведь нам нужен максимальный эпизод меньший данного

Comment: А вот имеем 2 сезона:
В 1 сезоне 12 серий, во втором - 8 серий.
Получается если мы ищем предыдущую серию от 1 серии 2 сезона - она должна быть равна 12 серии 1 сезона.

Comment: Т.е. предыдущая серия должна равняться последней серии предыдущего сезона.

Comment: А, точно, значит в условии на предыдущий сезон номер серии вообще проверять не надо

Comment: Что-то не догоняю, если честно.

Comment: И зачем вы задаете переменную @current_serial если ее нигде не используете

Comment: Я убрал её из сравнения, т.к. она мусорилась бы. Это кусок запроса основного, без лишних подзапросов и проверок.

Comment: Давайте рассуждать обычными словами, что такое предыдущая серия ? По моему это максимальная серия из максимального сезона удовлетворяющая условию "(серия < текущей И текущего сезона) ИЛИ сезон предыдущий". А вы зачем то проверяете номер серии на > текущей в предыдущем сезоне

Comment: А как задать ORDER BY на понятие "максимальная серия И максимальный сезон"?
ORDER BY _episode.episode, _season.season DESC 
не работает

Comment: Не работает в плане, что для "4 сезон 4 серия" он выдает предыдущую серию "4 сезон 1 серия"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ вы можете просмотреть на англоязычной версии сайта:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144441/mysql-find-previous-episode-in-serial/42144753#42144753

Для ленивых:

```
SET @current_episode = 1;
SET @current_season = 2;
SET @current_serial = 2;

SELECT * FROM `episode` _episode 
    LEFT JOIN season _season ON _episode.season_id = _season.id
    LEFT JOIN serial _serial ON _season.serial_id  = _serial.id 
WHERE 

    (_episode.episode < @current_episode AND _season.season = @current_season)
        OR 
    (_season.season < @current_season)

ORDER BY _season.season DESC, _episode.episode DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE CONCAT(serial,season,episode) < CONCAT(@serial,@season,@episode)
ORDER BY CONCAT(serial,season,episode) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Если значения могут быть многозначными — добавить `LPAD()`.